# property of complex integral, Conway volume 1

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about this, 
Let $ \gamma$ be a rectifiable curve and suppose that $f$ is a function continuous on {$\gamma$}. then:

$ | \int_{\gamma} f | \leq \int_{\gamma} |f| |dz| $

Note: $ \int_{\gamma} f |dz| = \int_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(t)) d|\gamma|(t) $

I have no idea how to start this.  any help would be great.

Comment: simply by writing $z = \gamma(t)$, $dz = \gamma'(t) dt$ :
$$\int_\Gamma f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$$
which is less than $\int_a^b |f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)| dt$ (and with $d|\gamma| = |\gamma'(t)| dt$ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(t_0 =a,t_1,...,t_n = b)$ be a partition of $[a,b]$.

Then
$| \sum_k f(\gamma(t_k)) (\gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1})) | \le \sum_k | f(\gamma(t_k)) | | \gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1}) |$.

Note that 
$V_{[a,t_{k-1}]}(\gamma) + | \gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1}) | \le V_{[a,t_{k}]}(\gamma)$, and since $|\gamma|(t) = V_{[a,t]}(\gamma)$, we have
$| \gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1}) | \le |\gamma|(t_k) - |\gamma|(t_{k-1}) = | |\gamma|(t_k) - |\gamma|(t_{k-1}) |$, and so
$| \sum_k f(\gamma(t_k)) (\gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1})) | \le \sum_k | f(\gamma(t_k)) ||\gamma|(t_k) - |\gamma|(t_{k-1}) |$.

Now take limits as the mesh size of the partition goes to zero and we get
$|\int_\gamma f dz | \le \int_\gamma |f| |dz|$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Khoata: Glad to be of help.